# JavaScript game loop playing catch up/blury/ghosted in chrome/browsers

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been trying to set up a javascript game loop and I have two issues I am running into.  I find that in chrome when I lose focus of the browser window and then click back the animation I have running does this weird "catch up" thing where it quickly runs through the frames it should of been rendering in the background.  I also have noticed that the animation is blury when moving at the current speed I have it at yet other people have been able to get their canvas drawings to move quickly and still look crisp.  I know their seems to be a lot out about this but I cant make sense of what my issue really is.  I thought this was a recommended way to create a game loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frame Test</title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"
        type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" src="js/jquery.hotkeys.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="js/key_status.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="js/util.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="js/sprite.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button1">
        Toggle Loop</button>
    <h1 id="frameCount">
        Game Loop Test</h1>
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="500">
<p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
</canvas>
    <script type='text/javascript'>



        // demo code used for playing around with javascript-canvas animations
        var frameCount = 0;
        var drawingCanvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
        // Check the element is in the DOM and the browser supports canvas
        if (drawingCanvas.getContext) {
            var context = drawingCanvas.getContext('2d');
            var x = 100;
            var y = 100;
            var right = true;
            context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            context.fillStyle = "Green";
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x, y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
            context.fill();

        }



        function Timer(settings) {
            this.settings = settings;
            this.timer = null;
            this.on = false;  //Bool that represents if the timer is running or stoped
            this.fps = settings.fps || 30;  //Target frames per second value
            this.interval = Math.floor(1000 / 30);
            this.timeInit = null;  //Initial time taken when start is called

            return this;
        }

        Timer.prototype =
            {
                run: function () {
                    var $this = this;

                    this.settings.run();
                    this.timeInit += this.interval;

                    this.timer = setTimeout(
                function () { $this.run() },
                this.timeInit - (new Date).getTime()
            );
                },

                start: function () {
                    if (this.timer == null) {
                        this.timeInit = (new Date).getTime();
                        this.run();
                        this.on = true;
                    }
                },

                stop: function () {
                    clearTimeout(this.timer);
                    this.timer = null;
                    this.on = false;
                },

                toggle: function () {

                    if (this.on) { this.stop(); }
                    else { this.start(); }
                }
            }

        var timer = new Timer({
            fps: 30,
            run: function () {
                //---------------------------------------------run game code here------------------------------------------------------
                //Currently Chorme is playing a catch up game with the frames to be drawn when the user leaves the browser window and then returns
                //A simple canvas animation is drawn here to try and figure out how to solve this issue.  (Most likely related to the timer implimentation)
                //Once figured out probably the only code in this loop should be something like
                //updateGameLogic();
                //updateGameCanvas();


                frameCount++;
                if (drawingCanvas.getContext) {
                    // Initaliase a 2-dimensional drawing context

                    //Canvas commands go here
                    context.clearRect((x - 52), 48, (x + 52), 104);

                    // Create the yellow face
                    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
                    context.fillStyle = "Green";
                    context.beginPath();
                    if (right) {
                        x = x + 6;
                        if (x > 500)
                            right = false;
                    } else {
                        x = x - 6;
                        if (x < 100)
                            right = true;
                    }
                    context.arc(x, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.stroke();
                    context.fill();
                }
                document.getElementById("frameCount").innerHTML = frameCount;
                //---------------------------------------------end of game loop--------------------------------------------------------
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function () { timer.toggle(); };
        frameCount++;
        document.getElementById("frameCount").innerHTML = frameCount;

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

-------------Update ---------------------

I have used requestanimation frame and that has solved the frame rate problam but I still get weird ghosting/bluring when the animation is running.  any idea how I should be drawing this thing?

Comment: Have you tried using `requestAnimationFrame()`? [link](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so part of your problem is that when you switch tabs, Chrome throttles down its performance.

Basically, when you leave, Chrome slows all of the calculations on the page to 1 or 2 fps (battery-saver, and more performance for the current tab).
Using setTimeout in the way that you have is basically scheduling all of these calls, which sit and wait for the user to come back (or at most are only running at 1fps).

When the user comes back, you've got hundreds of these stacked calls, waiting to be handled, and because they've ***all*** been scheduled earlier, they've all passed their "wait" time, so they're all going to execute as fast as possible (fast-forward), until the stack is emptied to where you have to start waiting 32ms for the next call.

A solution to this is to stop the timer when someone leaves -- pause the game.
On some browsers which support canvas games in meaningful ways, there is also support for a PageVisibility API.  You should look into it.
For other browsers, it'll be less simple, but you can tie to a blur event on the `window` for example.

Just be sure that when you restart, you also clear your interval for your updates.

Ultimately, I'd suggest moving over to `requestAnimationFrame, because it will intelligently handle frame rate, and also handle the throttling you see, due to the stacked calls, but your timer looks like a decent substitute for browsers which don't yet have it.

As for blurriness, that needs more insight.
Reasons off the top of my head, if you're talking about images, are either that your canvas' width/height are being set in CSS, somewhere, or your sprites aren't being used at a 1:1 scale from the image they're pulled from.

It can also come down to sub-pixel positioning of your images, or rotation.

Hope that helps a little.

...actually, after looking at your code again, try removing "width" and "height" from your canvas in HTML, and instead, change `canvas.width = 800; canvas.height = 500;` in JS, and see if that helps any.

Comment: I am more concerned with getting rid of ghosting/blur of animation.  I tried setting the canvas size manualy..no dice...no css is used on the canvas and sprites are 1:1 because I am drawing them using canvas built in drawing controls.